# COUNTA returning 1 when expect 0, even when IFNA is used

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a function in Sheets that is a QUERY wrapped in COUNTA to get the total number of values Column E dependent on a specific value in that same column, as well as a specific value in Column I. It works when the result isn't 0. If it's 0 I get a 1. I realize this is because it's counting the N/A as a value, but my efforts to resolve using IFERROR or IFNA are failing.

- This formula works and returns #N/A

  =QUERY(Data!A2:I,"SELECT E WHERE E = 'FRIT' AND I = '0001'")
- This formula works and returns 1 because it's counting the #N/A

  =IFNA(QUERY(Data!A2:I,"SELECT E WHERE E = 'FRIT' AND I = '0001'"),"0")
- I was expecting this formula to work and return 0, but it still returns 1

  =COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(Data!A2:I,"SELECT E WHERE E = 'FRIT' AND I = '0001'"),"0"))

Any advice on what I'm missing here? Are there limits on how many functions can be wrapped up? That's the only thing that I thought of that I can't find an answer on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was expecting this formula to work and return 0, but it still returns 1

well, 0 (zero) is 1 (one) value...

use:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(Data!A2:I,"SELECT E WHERE E = 'FRIT' AND I = '0001'")))
```

Comment: Wow, feel dumb now. Pretty obvious. Thanks!

Comment: I have one follow up I hope you can help with. I want to be able to copy this formula down a column but keep the sheet and cell reference static for the query. I tried (Data!$A2:$I, ... but that didn't work. When I copy down the cell reference keeps updating. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: @AndrewHarrell try: `=COUNTA(IFNA(QUERY(INDIRECT("Data!A2:I"),"SELECT Col5 WHERE Col5 = 'FRIT' AND Col9 = '0001'")))`